# Query takes too much time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have a issue with a query that take too much time to execute.
This is my query

```
SELECT U.user_id, C.c_id, U.username, U.email, R.reply
FROM users U, conversation C, conversation_reply R
WHERE CASE 
WHEN C.user_one =1
THEN C.user_two = U.user_id
WHEN C.user_two =1
THEN C.user_one = U.user_id
END 
AND C.c_id = R.c_id_fk
AND (
C.user_one =1
OR C.user_two =1
)
ORDER BY C.c_id DESC
```

I have 250788 total Recoderds in conversation_reply table that store the message details then this query give 10225 records in result and that take 7.291 sec.

Please give me the proper solution.

Comment: Do you want all of them on a single page?

Comment: There is no proper join in the query, you need to first turn this query into  an explicit join followed by indexing.

Comment: Thanks   I have already give the indexing.

Comment: I am also try the INNER JOIN But not up to the mark

Answer (score 1):

You should limit the search.

```
'...ORDER BY C.c_id DESC LIMIT 100'
```

Than after you show first 100 mesages you can AJAX for the rest of them, so the loading will be in background.

Comment: Thank you But I need the 1000 Record in first page so that I set 1000 limit then it takes to much time (3.9194 sec).

Comment: I dont know what kind of aplication you make but for web pages you can load information 1 by 1, or 10 by 10 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell database to forcefully use any index.
Like Below

```
USE INDEX (index1,index2)
```